# Programmatically toggle MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, mapkit

In my app, I added an `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` to my `UINavigationBar` which conveniently eliminates the need for a `CLLocationManager`. However, I want the map to be set to the current location immediately after the app loads, not just when the button is pressed. In addition, I would also like more control over how large the region that is displayed is. As of right now, I am stuck with the default value. If there is a way to in essence disable the button so I can give it my own functions, that would work too. This is my code (although I doubt there's much to see there):

```
let trackingLocationButton: UIBarButtonItem = MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem(mapView: map)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = trackingLocationButton
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To zoom in on the userLocation:

```
let location = mapView.userLocation
let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 500, longitudinalMeters: 500)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

to programmatically toggle the MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem:

```
trackingBBI.perform(trackingBBI.action)
```

or

```
mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.follow, animated: true)
```